# CSS modal backfall doesn't take up entire screen

Tags: html, css

I want the background of my modal in CSS to take up the entire screen (i.e. whole screen gets shadowed over except for the modal content itself). I think this may have to do with me giving other divs widths and heights based on vh and vw. Here's My Code:

```css
#modal {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  left: 40%;
  right: 30%;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#modal button {
  height: 40px;
  font: Hind Siliguri;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="modal">
    <h2>Choose a word: </h2>
    <button id = "choice1">Word1</button><button id= "choice2">Word2</button><button id = "choice3">Word3</button>
  </span>
```

Here are other elements I assigned dimensions based on vw/vh:

```
#verbal-hint-container{
  margin-right: 50%;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 40vw;
  background-color: #C3D898;
  border: 5px solid #160F29;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

verbal-hint-container is just a div that contains instantiated messages (from mustache library).

Is my hunch that assigning other elements dimensions based on vw/vh interferes with making an element span the entire screen right? Is there a workaround for this? If it matters, my css+html for my modal occurs later in those files than my css+html for all other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On **#modal** the *height* and *width* are using **=** instead of **:** thats why its not working properly. Change your **#modal** CSS to this:

   ```
   #modal {
     z-index: 1;
     position: fixed;
     left: 40%;
     right: 30%;
     top: 10%;
     display: none;
     background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
   }
   ```
2. *left*, *right*, and *top* on **#modal** are not necessary if your goal is to cover up the whole screen. This will only cause the modal to be placed at the wrong position.

Not really sure what you want to achieve here but I would suggest to remove / comment out the **display: none** first while debugging / creating new component / block

Answer (score 0):

Using Inspect element provides us with a way to find the classes in use by bootstrap.

Try adding the following CSS to your page:

```
.reveal-modal-bg {
    width: auto !important;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 40;
}
```

Adding this code should ensure that the background is fully covering the entire page.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I'm getting your question right. 
But here's an example where the modal background occupies 100% of the screen. 
I hope this will help you.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```